# save and find function not working in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am trying to save a blog post content to database and retrieve data from it. But the Functions stop executing when they enter the save and find functions.

The Functions are as follows :

```
blogapi.post('/add', function(req, res) {
    var blog = new Blog({
        title: req.body.title,
        author: req.body.author,
        blogDate: req.body.blogDate,
        blogLink: req.body.blogLink,
        shortDesc: req.body.shortDesc,
        blogImage: req.body.blogImage
    });
    blog.save(function(err) {
        if (err) {
            res.send(err);
            return;
        }
        res.json({message: 'Blog Post Added!'});
    });
});

blogapi.get('/view', function(req, res) {
    Blog.find({}, function(err, blogs) {
        if (err) {
            res.send(err);
            return;
        }
        res.json(blogs);
    });
});
```

The Blog Schema is as follows :

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var blogSchema = new Schema({
    title: {type: String, required: true},
    author: {type: String, required: true},
    blogDate: {type: String, required: true},
    blogLink: {type: String, required: true},
    shortDesc: {type: String, required: true},
    blogImage: {type: String, required: false}
});

blogSchema.pre('save', function(next){
    var blogPost = this;
    if (!blogPost.isModified('title')) {
        return next();
    }
    next();
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Blog', blogSchema);
```

I searched through various articles and found that indeed my execution while save stops in the pre but I have no clue why. I followed the answer given to a question here but it didn't solve my problem.

I still have no clue as to why find function is stopping.

Comment: How do you connect to the database `mongoose.connect` or `mongoose.createConnection` ?

Comment: @BertrandMartel mongoose.connect(config.database, { useMongoClient: true }, 
        function(err) {
            if (err) {
      console.log(err);
     } else {
  console.log('Connected to Database');
     }
        });